# Edit part of a Message Embed (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

I have a channel that contains 10 embedded messages (1 embed per message). Each embed is a leaderboard for people's best lap times, by Track.

The layout of each embed is

```
const trackName = new MessageEmbed
.setTitle(trackName) 
.addField(user1, lapTime)
.addField(user2, lapTime) 
.addField(user3, lapTime)
```

Assume for example the 3rd embed looks something like this:

| **Track 3 Name**

| John 37 seconds

| Chris 39 seconds

| Jeff 40 seconds

Beyond simply editing the embed and sending all the information updated manually, how could I update just one particular slot? For example, say Clark comes in with a 38 second lap, how would I move Chris to 3rd, remove Jeff, and add Clark to 2nd so the embed looks as such

| **Track 3 Name**

| John 37 seconds

| Clark 38 seconds

| Chris 39 seconds

Without changing any other embeds in the channel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I'm not %100 sure, but I believe the embed must be replaced with an entire new embed on edit

Comment: @elitezen I was hoping that wasn't the case. Was wondering if there's a way to simply assign a "label", for lack of better terminology, to each of the .addfields(), to be able to edit them.

Comment: Does your code work as intended at the moment? Or are you just trying to optimize

Comment: At the moment, I simply type `!pb` (personal best), it sends a message asking for the track name, awaits a track name, then a series of 3 .awaitMessages() to collect each User & Lap Time, stores all of it in variables, then .edit()'s the original embed with all the info(which obviously just overwrites the entire embed with the new MessageEmbed) - - and it works. Trying to optimize/shortcut so I don't have to input 7 different variables to edit the embed (track, user1, user2, user3, user1pb, user2pb, user3pb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Cannicide's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6901876/cannicide) helpful answer, it led me down the right track.

To achieve the end result of sorting times and overwriting existing times, I ended up with the following function. I require all times be submitted in the format: MINUTES:SECONDS (0:35 = 35s | 4:24 = 4m24s | 62:08 = 1h2m8s).

```
function editLb(theMessage, newUser, newTime) {
    //get the embed you want to edit
    let currentEmbed = theMessage.embeds[0];

    //Check all existing fields for the same newUser, if the same newUser
    //is found, replace that entire field with the name: "Placeholder"
    //and the value: "999:99". This will also remove any existing duplicates.
    currentEmbed.fields.forEach(field => {
        if (field.name == newUser) {
            field.name = `Placeholder`;
            field.value = `999:99`;
        }
    })

    //add the newUser and the newTime to a new field
    currentEmbed.addField(`${newUser}`, `${newTime}`);

    //sort all available fields effectively by seconds, by taking 
    // (minutes*60) + (seconds)
    currentEmbed.fields.sort((a, b) => Number((a.value.split(":")[0])*60 + (a.value.split(":")[1])) - Number((b.value.split(":")[0])*60 + (b.value.split(":")[1])));
    
    //If there are now 4 fields, remove the slowest(last) one.
    if (currentEmbed.fields.length == 4) currentEmbed.fields.splice(3, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to create an entirely new embed and input all of the information into it. You could get the current embed from the message, and edit the specific fields you need to edit. Here is an example that you could adapt to work with your system:

```js
function editTrack(msg, newUser, newTime) {
    //Assume `msg` is the message in the channel containing the embed you want to edit
    //currentEmbed is now the embed you want to edit
    let currentEmbed = msg.embeds[0];

    //Add `newUser` and its `newTime` to the embed as a new field, in the last position
    currentEmbed.addField(newUser, newTime);

    //Sorts the embed's fields by the lap times of each user, from lowest to highest
    //This example numerically sorts the fields by the number in their value
    //This does most of the work for you; the laps are now in the correct order
    currentEmbed.fields.sort((a, b) => Number(a.value.split(" second")[0]) - Number(b.value.split(" second")[0]));

    //If you want to display only the top 3, remove the 4th field of the embed (if any)
    if (currentEmbed.fields.length == 4) currentEmbed.fields.splice(3, 1);

    //Now, we need to edit the message with our updated embed (djs 13.x syntax)
    return msg.edit({embeds: [currentEmbed]});
}
```

I tested this `editTrack` method using one of my bots' eval commands:

BEFORE -
[image: First embed]

AFTER -
[image: Edited embed]

The original embed is successfully edited with the new information. And it only required the `Message` object containing the embed, the new lap's user, and the new lap's time.

---

**Edit** based on OP's comment:

For the answer to work when editing the track embed with an existing user, who has a new lap time, a slight modification needs to be made. Before removing the 4th field of the embed, you must do something like this:

```js
const names = new Set();
currentEmbed.fields = currentEmbed.fields.filter(field =>
    !names.has(field.name) && names.add(field.name)
);
```

Here's what that code is doing. First, we create a `Set`. Sets are iterable structures similar to arrays, but they can only contain unique values. We can therefore use sets to ensure there are no repeats of a user's name. Next, we filter the fields; only the fields whose user is not already contained in `names` will remain. If a user's name is not already in `names`, it gets added to the set via `.add()`. And because the fields are already sorted with the quickest lap time coming first, only the quickest lap of a given user will remain; any longer lap times by the same user will be filtered out.

Note that I only tested this edit briefly, let me know if there are any logical errors or further issues caused by it (or if it fails to work entirely).

Comment: Trying this myself with eval. I've got the embed sent with a title and 3 fields each containing lapUser, lapTime.      I then fetch the channel & the message with `const chan = client.channels.cache.get('682014685431595027');
    const msg = chan.messages.fetch('883361737313751120');`
I'm getting an error at `let currentEmbed = msg.embeds[0];` stating "cannot read property embeds of undefined". I am also on v12.

Comment: Make sure to `await` (or use `.then()` on) the result of `.fetch()`, as it returns a `Promise`. If you're using v12, the only change you'll need to make will be on this line: `return msg.edit({embeds: [currentEmbed]});`. You'll need to change that to `return msg.edit(currentEmbed)` on v12.

Comment: If fetching is not working for you, you could also just directly refer to the message created when sending the original embed for your testing purposes, i.e. `message.channel.send(originalEmbed).then(msg => ...)`

Comment: Had already changed the msg.edit() function. I'll add await. Forgot to do that, I normally do. Ty, will reply soon.

Comment: Had to elaborate on part of your code, because the format I'm using for the lapTime is actually minutes:seconds, so where you have `currentEmbed.fields.sort((a, b) => Number(a.value.split(" second")[0]) - Number(b.value.split(" second")[0]));` I changed that to `currentEmbed.fields.sort((a, b) => Number(a.value.split(":")[0] * 60 + a.value.split(":")[1]) - Number(b.value.split(":")[0] * 60 + b.value.split(":")[1]));`
To sort them effectively by total seconds. Other than that, very very neat idea with sorting fields. Just for shits and giggles, how does one sort by .addField(name, data) name?

Comment: If you mean sorting the field names/titles alphabetically, i.e. `["John", "Clark", "Chris"]` -> `["Chris", "Clark", "John"]`, then you just need to use `String.localeCompare()` along with `Array.sort()` for that. Example: `fields.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`.

Comment: So, unintentional side effect i've been trying to figure out for 2 days. If someone beats their best lapTime, using the command doesnt overwrite a previous best laptTime. It just adds another. So exmaple would be: John 35 seconds, John 37 seconds, Clark 38 seconds, when i want to show 3 different people. Currently the only way i can fix that is by editting the original message with a new embed manually inputted with eval. Any suggestions on comparing the name field to the existing name fields, and if the name field matches, update that fields's value, and then sort

Comment: @eXC0n Edited the answer with a possible solution to that problem. Also, note that the new edited solution to that particular issue must come before the `.splice()` line, or the lap data of the last user will be lost.